# Programmatically Identify CMS by URL

Tags: php, api, content-management-system

Is there any other way to detect CMS from URL? If yes, is there any available API in PHP o any other language?
The site http://whatcms.org/ is an example of what i have in mind; how does it do the detection?

Comment: WhatCMS explains its algorithm on its search page. Personally, I simply search the HTML file for a string like Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla!, Squarespace, Magento, OpenCart, etc. Or else search for diminutives used in the stylings like wp-, etc. Note that there's a lot of small market-share CMSs whose diminutives you have to learn by experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the meta tag for generator.
Most CMS have their name and version advertised there.

This is the tag you're after.

```
<meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
```

This code will try and find the tag to extract the `content` attribute.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://joomla.org');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$generators = $xpath->query('//html/head/meta[@name="generator"]');

echo $generators->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
```

This code echo's `Joomla! - Open Source Content Management`

Comment: It would be great if you can provide link or example how can i check meta tag of any url.

Comment: You will have to put some effort into it, @Bart's code is a good start. Not every CMS will be this kind, nor will everyone running Joomla have that meta-tag. You will have to do some parsing and do qualified guesses based on how the code is structured, looking at specific "markers" in the code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nor Wappalyzer nor whatCMS detect the CMS from the URL, they download the code, and check the meta-data. If you put some effort in that, you can do this yourself too using curl to retrieve the page and then parsing out the meta-data, scanning for keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please provide a sample code or unique meta information for commonly used cms ?

Comment: Sure, for Drupal: <meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" /> and for Wordpress: <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.1" /> So as you can see it is mostly the "generator" Meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [Detect-CMS PHP library](https://github.com/Krisseck/Detect-CMS) written by [Krisseck](https://github.com/Krisseck).

From the README.md:

```
include("Detect-CMS/Detect-CMS.php");
$domain = "http://google.com";
$cms = new DetectCMS($domain);
if($cms->getResult()) {
    echo "Detected CMS: ".$cms->getResult();
} else {
    echo "CMS couldn't be detected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a common CMS is used (e.g. OpenCart , WordPress , Magento , Joomla , etc), Chrome / Firefox extension, [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/download) will be handy.

Comment: but i need to check it in my code. as depending on different CMS i need to perform different action.